# I get an error why I try to compile D-Link drivers with `make`

Tags: drivers, lubuntu, compiling, virtualization, binutils

I am running Lubuntu 17.04 inside a VMWare virtual machine. I am trying to compile and install the driver for my `D-Link DUB-1312 Gigabit Ethernet Adapter`. However, I get the error in the code block below when I try to run `make`. After reading similar questions elsewhere, I've seen other users ask whether `binutils` is installed. It is installed on my Lubuntu system. I'm an inexperienced Linux user.

```
make -C /lib/modules/4.10.0-19-generic/build SUBDIRS=/home/magnus/Documents/DUB modules
make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.10.0-19-generic'
arch/x86/Makefile:140: CONFIG_X86_X32 enabled but no binutils support
./scripts/gcc-version.sh: line 25: gcc: command not found
./scripts/gcc-version.sh: line 26: gcc: command not found
make[1]: gcc: Command not found
make[1]: gcc: Command not found
make[1]: gcc: Command not found
make[1]: gcc: Command not found
make[1]: gcc: Command not found
  CC [M]  /home/magnus/Documents/DUB/DUB-13X2.o
/bin/sh: 1: gcc: not found
scripts/Makefile.build:301: recipe for target '/home/magnus/Documents/DUB/DUB-13X2.o' failed
make[2]: *** [/home/magnus/Documents/DUB/DUB-13X2.o] Error 127
Makefile:1524: recipe for target '_module_/home/magnus/Documents/DUB' failed
make[1]: *** [_module_/home/magnus/Documents/DUB] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.10.0-19-generic'
Makefile:30: recipe for target 'default' failed
make: *** [default] Error 2
```

Does anyone have any tips? Been stuck on this for too long.

EDIT: After installing `gcc` like Arun suggested, I've made some progress. I now get a new error:

```
make -C /lib/modules/4.10.0-19-generic/build SUBDIRS=/home/magnus/Documents/DUB modules
make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.10.0-19-generic'
  CC [M]  /home/magnus/Documents/DUB/DUB-13X2.o
/home/magnus/Documents/DUB/DUB-13X2.c:55:6: error: macro "__TIME__" might prevent reproducible builds [-Werror=date-time]
  " " __TIME__ " " __DATE__ "\n"
      ^~~~~~~~
/home/magnus/Documents/DUB/DUB-13X2.c:55:19: error: macro "__DATE__" might prevent reproducible builds [-Werror=date-time]
  " " __TIME__ " " __DATE__ "\n"
                   ^~~~~~~~
cc1: some warnings being treated as errors
scripts/Makefile.build:301: recipe for target '/home/magnus/Documents/DUB/DUB-13X2.o' failed
make[2]: *** [/home/magnus/Documents/DUB/DUB-13X2.o] Error 1
Makefile:1524: recipe for target '_module_/home/magnus/Documents/DUB' failed
make[1]: *** [_module_/home/magnus/Documents/DUB] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.10.0-19-generic'
Makefile:30: recipe for target 'default' failed
make: *** [default] Error 2
```

For anyone who might ask, this is my Makefile:

```
CURRENT = $(shell uname -r)
#TARGET = usbnet
#OBJS   = usbnet.o
TARGET  = DUB-13X2
OBJS    = DUB-13X2.o
MDIR    = drivers/net/usb
KDIR    = /lib/modules/$(CURRENT)/build
#KDIR   = /root/Desktop/Android/UBIQCONN/android-3.0
SUBLEVEL= $(shell uname -r | cut -d '.' -f 3 | cut -d '.' -f 1 | cut -d '-' -f 1 | cut -d '_' -f 1)
USBNET  = $(shell find $(KDIR)/include/linux/usb/* -name usbnet.h)

ifneq (,$(filter $(SUBLEVEL),14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21))
MDIR = drivers/usb/net
#USBNET = $(shell find $(KDIR)/$(MDIR)/* -name usbnet.h)
endif

#ifneq (,$(filter $(SUBLEVEL),21 22 23 24))
#USBNET = $(shell find $(KDIR)/$(MDIR)/* -name usbnet.h)
#endif

#$(if $(USBNET),,$(error $(KDIR)/$(MDIR)/usbnet.h not found. please refer to readme file for the detailed description))

EXTRA_CFLAGS = -DEXPORT_SYMTAB
PWD = $(shell pwd)
DEST = /lib/modules/$(CURRENT)/kernel/$(MDIR)

obj-m      := $(TARGET).o

default:
    make -C $(KDIR) SUBDIRS=$(PWD) modules

$(TARGET).o: $(OBJS)
    $(LD) $(LD_RFLAG) -r -o $@ $(OBJS)

install:
    su -c "cp -v $(TARGET).ko $(DEST) && /sbin/depmod -a"

clean:
    $(MAKE) -C $(KDIR) SUBDIRS=$(PWD) clean

.PHONY: modules clean

-include $(KDIR)/Rules.make
```

EDIT2:
I added the flag, -Wno-date-time, like Arun suggested. This made the driver compile! After struggling a bit further, I also managed to install the driver. If your answer, Arun, had been an "answer" and not a comment, I would have marked it as a solution.

Comment: You must install gcc `sudo apt install gcc`

Comment: I did, and that gave me some progress. Thank you! Unfortunately, I now have a new error.

Comment: Add  `-Wno-date-time` to EXTRA_CFLAGS

Comment: Doesn't this use the driver `asix` that is already included in 4.10.0-xx? Please edit your question to add the result of `lsusb`  Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: @Arun you can make your comments into an answer